# Is Commerce Stripe any more or less secure than Commerce Paypal?

Tags: 7, commerce, security

The very first thing the [Commerce Stripe module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_stripe) states is this:

> As of the implementation of PCI-DSS 3.0 (January 2015), this module is
> intended to work within the requirements of the Self Assessment
> Questionnaire A-EP. If you are not familiar with the requirements of
> SAQ A-EP, which includes a wide range of security practices as well as
> quarterly penetration scans by a PCI certified third party vendor, you
> should not use this module.

However later on it says

> Features
>
> PCI-compliant integration/payments. Utilizes the stripe.js library so
> that sensitive card data never touches your server.

The [Commerce Paypal](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_paypal) page makes no mention of PCI-DSS. If card data never touches my server what changes do I need to make? Do I need an SSL cert?